# Exception '''IdentityUserLogin<string>' requires a primary key to be defined."

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, sql-view

I am building an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Blazor app in which I need data sets which are the results of tables with a join on ASP.NET users. For the first case I have chosen to use a View in my database

```sql
CREATE VIEW vwGuardianList
AS
    SELECT        
        Users.Id AS UserId,
        Users.FirstName,  Users.LastName,
        Users.Email,
        Users.PhoneNumber,
        g.FirstGuardianAddress1, g.FirstGuardianAddress2,
        g.FirstGuardianCity, g.FirstGuardianPostcode,
        g.FirstGuardianRelationship, g.FirstGuardianAgreed,
        g.FirstGuardianAgeedDate,
        g.SecondGuardianFirstName, g.SecondGuardianLastName,
        g.SecondGuardianEmail, g.SecondGuardianPhone,
        g.SecondGuardianAddress1 AS SecondAddress1,
        g.SecondGuardianAddress2 AS SecondAddress2,
        g.SecondGuardianCity, g.SecondGuardianPostcode,
        g.SecondGuardianRelationship,
        g.SecondGuardianAgreed, g.SecondGuardianAgeedDate,
        g.Id as GuardianId
    FROM 
        Guardians g 
    INNER JOIN  
        AspNetUsers Users ON g.FirstGuardianUserId = Users.Id
```

I have a data model class:

```cs
public class GuardianList
{
    [Key]
    public string? UserId { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string? FirstGuardianAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string? FirstGuardianAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string? FirstGuardianCity { get; set; }
    public string? FirstGuardianPostCode { get; set; }
    public string? FirstGuardianRelationship { get; }
    public bool FirstGuardianAgreed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FirstGuardianAgreedDate { get; set; }
    public string? SecondGuardianFirstName { get; set; }
    public string? SecondGuardianLastName { get; set; }
    public string? SecondGuardianEmail { get; set; }
    public string? SecondGuardianPhone { get; set; }
    public string? SecondGuardianAddress1 { get; set; }
    public string? SecondGuardianAddress2 { get; set; }
    public string? SecondGuardianCity { get; set; }
    public string? SecondGuardianPostCode { get; set; }
    public string? SecondGuardianRelationship { get; }
    public bool SecondGuardianAgreed { get; set; }
    public DateTime? SecondGuardianAgreedDate { get; set; }
    public string? GuardianId { get; set; }
}
```

And I have configured the `ApplicationDBContext` as follows:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>(options)
{
        public DbSet<GuardianDetails> Guardians { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MemberDetails> Members { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VolunteerDetails> Volunteers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teams> Teams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<VolunteerTeams> VolunteersTeams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GuardianList> vwGuardianList { get; set; }
    
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<GuardianList>(c =>
                {
                    c.HasAlternateKey("UserId");
                    c.ToView(nameof(vwGuardianList));
                    c.Property(x => x.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
                });
        }
}
```

**The problem**

The solution builds ok . However when a user attempts to login, the following exception occurs

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

I have tried to add

Comment: The error appears to explain how to resolve it?

Comment: In your class you define a `[Key]` property whereas the help explains you need to set the class as `[Keyless]`

Comment: thank you. I changed this however the error still occurs

Comment: If you really changed it you need to edit your question to show us *exactly* your code and error i.e. a [mre]

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. Of course, the error is self-explanatory. But where do you get it? What is the code when a User attempts to login? While it is common to have `ApplicationUser` derived from `User`, you clearly did something beyond that. What is the definition of `IdentityUserLogin`?

Comment: The exception has nothing to do with the presented code. Except that you forgot to call `base.OnModelCreating` at the beginning of your override, thus base `IdentityDbContext` fluent configuration of the identity related entities has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was provided by Ivan Stoev

The exception has nothing to do with the presented code. Except that you forgot to call base.OnModelCreating at the beginning of your override, thus base IdentityDbContext fluent configuration of the identity related entities has no effect. –